# Build C# Xamarin.Mac library using VisualStudio for Windows

Tags: c#, windows, macos, xamarin

Is there any way to build Xamarin.Mac C# library with native Mac functionality using VisualStudio for Windows ?

Comment: Please read this carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As of this moment no.

> Xamarin.Mac application development requires:
>
> - A Mac computer running macOS High Sierra (10.13) or higher. Xcode 9 or higher.
> - The latest version of Xamarin.Mac and Visual Studio for Mac.

[Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac)